# Means and SDs of a list of variables

Tags: list, stata

I have the following code in Stata that I am trying to translate to python

```
    foreach var in income_pc_r income_village_pc_r income_migration exp_total_pc_r sav_cash12_any_r sav_cash12_amtcon_pc_r anygorl_r_ffv gorl_r_ffv_condamt anygorl_g_ffv gorl_g_ffv_condamt hhsize_r migrant_r {   if inlist("`var'","income_pc_r","income_village_pc_r","income_migration","exp_total_pc_r","savelast12mo_condamt","gorl_r_ffv_condamt","gorl_g_ffv_condamt") {       
qui sum `var', det      
local mean=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")         
local sd  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f")         
qui sum `var' if treat==0, det      
local meanc=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")        
local sdc  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f")        
qui sum `var' if treat==1, det      
local meant=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")        
local sdt  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f")        
file write ofile " `label`var'' & `mean' & `meanc' & `meant' \\" _n ///
                             "              & (`sd') & (`sdc') & (`sdt') \\" _n     }   else {      
qui sum `var', det      
local mean=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")         
local sd =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")      
qui sum `var' if treat==0, det      
local meanc=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")        
local sdc  =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")        
qui sum `var' if treat==1, det      
local meant=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")        
local sdt  =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")        
file write ofile " `label`var'' & `mean' & `meanc' & `meant' \\" _n ///
                             "              & (`sd') & (`sdc') & (`sdt') \\" _n     }        }
```

Does Stata only take those observations in calculation of mean and SD for each variable, for which all the variables have a non null value? Or does it treat each variable individually?

Comment: Although you are translating this to Python (and thus, superficially, the python tag appears to be in scope), your question is purely about the inner workings of Stata. As such, I have removed the Python tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, each variable is treated separately, so a non-missing value will be included in a calculation regardless of whether missing values exist in the same observation for other variables.

It's not your purpose, but it can be simplified.

1. `quietly` can be said once, not repeatedly.
2. `summarize` by itself yields mean and SD; the `detail` option is overkill.
3. Only one `file write` statement is needed.

Necessarily I can't test this rewrite.

```
quietly foreach var in income_pc_r income_village_pc_r income_migration exp_total_pc_r sav_cash12_any_r sav_cash12_amtcon_pc_r anygorl_r_ffv gorl_r_ffv_condamt anygorl_g_ffv gorl_g_ffv_condamt hhsize_r migrant_r {   

if inlist("`var'","income_pc_r","income_village_pc_r","income_migration","exp_total_pc_r","savelast12mo_condamt","gorl_r_ffv_condamt","gorl_g_ffv_condamt") {       
    sum `var'     
    local mean=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")         
    local sd  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f") 
        
    sum `var' if treat==0     
    local meanc=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")        
    local sdc  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f")    
    
    sum `var' if treat==1    
    local meant=string(r(mean),"%10.0f")        
    local sdt  =string(r(sd),  "%10.0f")      
}   

else {      
    sum `var'     
    local mean=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")         
    local sd  =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")      

    sum `var' if treat==0    
    local meanc=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")        
    local sdc  =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")   
     
    sum `var' if treat==1     
    local meant=string(r(mean),"%10.2f")        
    local sdt  =string(r(sd),  "%10.2f")  
} 
      
file write ofile " `label`var'' & `mean' & `meanc' & `meant' \\" _n ///
                             "              & (`sd') & (`sdc') & (`sdt') \\" _n     

}
```